# Clojure app with local jar file, how to push to Heroku?

Tags: clojure, heroku

I have a Clojure WebNoir app that uses one of my own jar files. How do I push this application to heroku properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do this with Clojure / Leiningen but with Java / Maven you can setup a local Maven Repo (in the git repo) containing the JARs:
http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I tried the local Maven repo solution proposed by James Ward, but I didn't know how to combine it with leiningen.

I solved it by pushing my own jar to Clojars. It is actually quite simple: http://clojars.org/